# Get new item uploaded in AWS DynamoDB table streaming to Lambda using python

Tags: python, aws-lambda, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I created a framework that saves information in DynamoDB table, I need the last uploaded item, the DynamoDB table looks like this:

```
{'Table': {'AttributeDefinitions': [{'AttributeName': 'ID',
    'AttributeType': 'S'}],
  'TableName': 'Bulk_query_database',
  'KeySchema': [{'AttributeName': 'ID', 'KeyType': 'HASH'}],
  'TableStatus': 'ACTIVE',
  'CreationDateTime': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 6, 21, 58, 20, 293000, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
  'ProvisionedThroughput': {'LastDecreaseDateTime': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 6, 22, 8, 40, 735000, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
   'NumberOfDecreasesToday': 0,
   'ReadCapacityUnits': 1,
   'WriteCapacityUnits': 1},
  'TableSizeBytes': 59,
  'ItemCount': 1,
```

[image]

So far now I have connect DynamoDB stream as a trigger for a Lambda function, this fuction should print the last element inserted in the table The query im using is this:

```
dynamodb_resource = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name="us-east-1")
table = dynamodb_resource.Table('Bulk_query_database')
response = table.query(KeyConditionExpression=Key('ID').eq('I CANT MAKE IT WORK UNLESS I USE THE ID STRING'))
items = response['Items']
print(items)
```

There is no response using this query, what I can do to get last element loaded into the table.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't so clear. From my understanding you want to Query the item which is stored in DynamoDB highlighted by the image you shared. To do this you need to set the value of ID:

```
response = table.query(KeyConditionExpression=Key('ID').eq('3P3AD596A'))
items = response['Items']
```

In DynamoDB items are stored based on the key, in your case ID and to retrieve those items you need to do so by passing the key value to your requests.

Comment: I’ll try to be more clear and edit this, I want to get always the last ID, every time a new item is uploaded get the latest ID

Comment: When a new item is uploaded it's streamed to your lambda function and should appear in the event variable. The access pattern you are trying to achieve using Query is not possible.

Comment: Thank you now it makes sense that is not possible, got it                                                                                                       `import json

print('Loading function')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))
    for record in event['Records']:
        print(record['eventID'])
        print(record['eventName'])
        print("DynamoDB Record: " + json.dumps(record['dynamodb'], indent=2))
    return 'Successfully processed {} records.'.format(len(event['Records']))`